# Android room find row from column

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

In my table I have one column ids and I store a list of ids. To save it I do TypeConverters

```
class IdsConverter {
    @TypeConverter
    fun storedStringToMyObjects(data: String?): List<Long?>? {
        if (data == null) {
            return Collections.emptyList()
        }
        val listType: Type = object : TypeToken<List<Long?>?>() {}.type
        return Gson().fromJson(data, listType)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun myObjectsToStoredString(myObjects: List<Long?>?): String? {
        if (myObjects == null || myObjects.isEmpty()) {
            return ""
        }
        return Gson().toJson(myObjects)
    }
}
```

but now I try to find a row when I have id = 2 and in query I can not do it

I write this query bu I do not nknow it is a good idea:

```
select *  FROM  test WHERE  (ids LIKE '%2,%' or ids LIKE '%,2,'or ids LIKE '%2' or ids = '2' or ids like '2,%')
```

Comment: Did you solve a problem ?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to save ids in one column of one row as json me be will be more comfortable to use sqlite's [json extension](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html) for this you will need a custom build of sqlite like [this](https://github.com/requery/requery) (and you will get some others benefits)
Examples with select queries you can find [in paragraph 4.13.1 of sqlite docs](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html).

But your solution looks like working :)

And you have other option: save each id in new row.